# Discrepancy Between Nonce for Single Block

Tags: nonce, blockchain-explorer

I'm looking at nonce data from blockchain.info for block #1 ( https://blockchain.info/block/00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048 ) and it shows a nonce value of **2573394689** However when I take a look at blockcypher.com ( https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/1 ) they report a nonce value of **2083236893** for the first block.

Is this a mistake? Is it possible for there to be a conflict in the true nonce? When I check block #2 both sites show the exact same nonce.

Answer (score 2):

The block presented with the second link ([api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/1](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/1)) is not the same as the one presented with [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048).

"**api.blockcypher.com**" says block 1 (Height=1) has a "previous block" of all zeroes:
[image]
but [that is the block with Height=0](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/block-height), not with Height=1 !.

One could argue that "api.blockcypher.com" starts counting (oddly) on "1", but the problem is that [their next block](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/2) (block 2) has a "previous block" of "00000000839a8..." (correct) which in fact is not their block 1...

That is, **there is a gap in their API**, and the block with a "previous block"="000000000019d66..." or **block with Height=1, is not accessible** using block count:

- "api.blockcypher.com" block 1 is really the block 0 (Height=0), and
- their block 2 is the correct block 2 (Height=2), and so
- **the block 1 that you are trying to see is unreachable in that API** (!).

That also means that **Nonce=2573394689** for [block 1 from blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048) is the correct value.